# MapStruct, map inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, mapping, mapstruct

I have 2 entities `Vehicle`, which is an *interface*, and `VehicleDto`, a *class*.

`Vehicle` has 2 *subtypes*: `Car` and `Truck`. All 3 of them have a field `name`.

`VehicleDto` has 2 *fields* `Car` and `Truck`, and only one of those may have a value.

How do I map the subtypes `Car` and `Truck` to the class `VehicleDto` so that the appropriate field of the `VehicleDto` is filled in with the `name` value of the subtype?

Currently I have this:

```
@Mapping(source = "name", target = "Car")
@Mapping(source = "name", target = "Truck")
VehicleDto mapToVehicle(Vehicle vehicle);
```

But that obviously does not work because now both `Car` and `Truck` fields of `VehicleDto` are filled in.

I also tried something like this

```
@Mapping(source = "name", target = "Car")
VehicleDto mapToVehicle(Car car);
@Mapping(source = "name", target = "Truck")
VehicleDto mapToVehicle(Truck truck);
```

But that also doesn't work properly.

What's a good way to implement this behavior? The reference guide of MapStruct was not very clear to me.

Comment: Have you tried fully qualifying your target classes? e.g. ```target = "path.to.package.Car"```

Comment: Yes, I simplified my question. But that is not the issue.

Comment: The second option with 2 methods actually works for me. What did mapstruct generated for you?

Comment: What is wrong with the second approach? Do you have some errors from MapStruct?